# Why my UIButton doesn't display in my subview? iPad App

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uibutton

Could somebody help me to understand why my UIButton doesn't display in my custom UIView?
In the code below I posted initWithFrame method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
    self.backgroundColor =[UIColor whiteColor];

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,frame.size.width, 50)];
    toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissNewInvoiceView:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *saveBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(saveNewInvoice:)];
    [saveBarButton setEnabled:NO];
    NSArray *arrayOfItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:cancelBarButton,flexibleSpace, saveBarButton, nil];
    [toolbar setItems:arrayOfItems];

    UILabel *headerViewLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(335, 15, 200, 20)];
    headerViewLabel.text = @"New Invoice";
    [toolbar addSubview:headerViewLabel];

    [self addSubview:toolbar];

    UIButton *selectCustomerButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 200, 60, 60)];
    selectCustomerButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Farmer.png"];

    [self addSubview:selectCustomerButton];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:selectCustomerButton];

    UILabel *invoiceNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 55, 150, 25)];
    [invoiceNumberLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:14]];
    invoiceNumberLabel.text = @"Invoice number:";
    [self addSubview:invoiceNumberLabel];

    UITextField *invoiceNumberField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 53, 150, 30)];
    [invoiceNumberField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:25]];
    invoiceNumberField.placeholder = @"25/13";
    [self addSubview:invoiceNumberField];

    UILabel *dateOfCreationLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 55, 150, 25)];
    [dateOfCreationLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:14]];
    dateOfCreationLabel.text = @"Date of creation:";
    [self addSubview:dateOfCreationLabel];







}
return self;}
```

Why UILabels are displaying properly by implement addSubview method while UIButtons are not?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
selectCustomerButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Farmer.png"]
```

Use

```
[selectCustomerButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Farmer.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The button sets its own image views image depending on its state, you don't access and set the image view's image yourself.

Comment: Thanks jrturton & Leijonien for your quick answers

Answer (score 0):

The button will be just invisible in case the image is not loaded/shown properly. As jrturton already said, you should use another method to set the image.

To figure out if the button is 'there', you can give the button a backgroundcolor like this:

```
selectCustomerButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

If you see a red box, you know the image is not properly loaded or maybe not even found.

Comment: `[UIColor redColor]`: the layout debugger's friend